# Copy a large amount of data of a specific format/pattern from one Excel file to another Excel file with different data pattern?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to **Copy some data (of a specific pattern**) from one Excel file and then **Paste that data to another Excel file but in a different pattern**. I also want to skip a certain number of rows from source file on a specific pattern ( copy data from 5 rows then skip next 5 rows , then copy data from next 5 rows and skip next 5 rows and so on).
My Source file contains about **80,000 rows** so copying manually using simple copy and paste using mouse clicks is very slow procedure and time consuming. 
Please tell me that what is the **VBA Macro code** for this specific problem that copy all that data automatically fulfilling the criteria. Thanks!

This is the Image of both files explaining the criteria of copy/paste: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wVjIfPSFkoSPw08rzVPdzqluKGynNKKT

Comment: Please note that because StackOverflow is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might help you to improve your question.

Comment: If you make the effort to search on here, there are several posts with code doing that type of thing, you will probably have to edit to meet your individual requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have Solved the issue.** Thanks for everyone giving **negative** feedback **for free**. If you can not post good comments then at least do not post bad comments. It is the **Simplest Task** to criticize someone.

By the way if anyone have this type of problem then this is the simple solution code written by me in Python:

```
import csv

#loading Source CSV file and parse it into list of integer numbers
with open('Source.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    scr_data_list = []
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','):
        scr_data_list.append(row[0]) # careful here with [0]
csvfile.close()

#print scr_data_list
#print "\n"

temp_scr_list = []  # temp list to store 5 values from Source list
temp_des_list = []  # temp list to store 9 numbers drived from "temp_scr_list"
des_data_list = []   # Destination List contaning whole data
step = 5
i = 0
while i < len(scr_data_list):

    j = 0
    while j <5:
        temp_scr_list.append(float(scr_data_list[i+j]))
        j = j+1

    # Main logic of this program
    #print temp_scr_list

    temp_des_list.append(temp_scr_list[2]) # value at -20 offset
    temp_des_list.append(temp_scr_list[2]+0.05) # value at -14 offset (derived)
    temp_des_list.append(temp_scr_list[1]-0.2) # value at -10 offset (derived)
    temp_des_list.append(temp_scr_list[1]) # value at -5 offset

    temp_des_list.append(temp_scr_list[0]) # value at 0 offset

    temp_des_list.append(temp_scr_list[3]) # value at 5 offset
    temp_des_list.append(temp_scr_list[3]-0.2) # value at 10 offset (derived)
    temp_des_list.append(temp_scr_list[4]+0.05) # value at 14 offset (derived)
    temp_des_list.append(temp_scr_list[4]) # value at 20 offset

    des_data_list.extend(temp_des_list)

    # step 5 values forward
    i=i+5


    # clear the lists
    temp_scr_list = []
    temp_des_list = []  

print len(des_data_list)


# write the numbers from "des_data_list" list to a CSV file
with open('Destination.csv', 'wb') as writeFile:
    for r in des_data_list:
        writeFile.write(str(r) + "\n")


writeFile.close()
```